# Editing Count(CASE WHEN to sum an Aggregate Value

Tags: sql, case, teradata

I am using CASE WHEN in my select statement to count the number of records where a condition is true:

```
 COUNT(CASE WHEN CAST(EVENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE) 
                 - CONTRACT_EFFECTIVE_DATE = 1 THEN 1 END) AS "1 day",
```

That works fine.

Now I am attempting to apply the same condition but to sum the values in a column where it is true, rather than counting the records. Here is what I have tried:

```
 (CASE WHEN CAST(EVENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE) 
          - CONTRACT_EFFECTIVE_DATE = 0 THEN SUM(DWELL_MINUTES) END) AS "0 day",
```

But that gave error "Selected non aggregate must be part of the associated group".

I tried some more variations with no success.

How would I sum the values contained in DWELL_MINUTES when `CAST(EVENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE) - CONTRACT_EFFECTIVE_DATE = 0`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the aggregation function in your original query from `COUNT` to `SUM`:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(EVENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE) - 
              CONTRACT_EFFECTIVE_DATE = 0 THEN DWELL_MINUTES END) AS "0 day"
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Accepting @Thorsten only because got there first

Comment: @DougFirr No problem with you accepting that answer, since it is correct. But you should look with more detail at the timestamps of the answers

Answer (score 4):

Do it the other way round, just like with COUNT. Do the evaluation per record and aggregate the results:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(EVENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE) 
     - CONTRACT_EFFECTIVE_DATE = 0 THEN DWELL_MINUTES END) AS "0 day",
```

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer, but actually Lamak was quicker, so you should accept his one.